# How do I express an include on an enum field?

Tags: enums, include, ruby-on-rails-5, conditional-statements

I'm using Rails 5.  I have a field in my model that is an enum.  When I want to check if it is one of three values, I'm doing this

```
book.status == :read || book.status == :incomplete || book.status == :not_started
```

Is there a more concise way to write the above?  Maybe it's already as concise as it can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails' enums give you access to some class and instance methods. One of the instance methods is a boolean check. So you could rewrite your expression as:

`book.read? || book.incomplete? || book.not_started?`

[Rails Enum Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)